# Why does phusion passenger ask for factory_girl_rails gem while in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, factory-bot

Everything is in the question :
Why does phusion passenger ask for factory_girl_rails gem while in production mode ?

My Gemfile does countains only this line about factory_girl_rails :

```
group :development, :test do
  # BUG version 4.2.0 needs to ass factory-girl in developpement https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/issues/89
  # Ressource : https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

My Phusion passenger confirm on the error screen that he is running as production server :

```
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV)
production
```

What's wrong.

As workaround is harmfull to put factory_girl_rails gem into production ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was coming from the my **Gemfile.lock**

At some point, I made a mistake by doing a `bundle install` which installed all gems for Developement, Test, and Production.

When I realized that I uninstalled manualy each gem with `gem uninstall <onegem>` command for each gem.

Then I made a `bundle install --without development test` command.

But I forgot to delete the **Gemfile.lock** before to do that.
SO I think passenger was somehow using the **Gemfile.lock** to do some check.

I solved this by using the `rvm gemset empty` command which uninstall gems from the current gemset in use and also delete the **Gemfile.lock**.

Then I applied again the `bundle install --without development test` command.
Then the error message from Passenger about missing factory_girl_rails was gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Capistrano with Passenger you can add this line in the deploy.rb:

set :bundle_without, [:development, :test]